# How to convert rds mysql latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql, sql, rds, iso-8859-1

I want to convert our production database from latin1 to utf8. 
we are using amazon rds mysql. 
Please provide step by step. Will there be any downtime?

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

i use above query to convert each table.

Is it good a way? I need to do one by one or is there any other way to do in one step?

Answer (score 1):

Change in PRODUCT server is always crucial. Lot of consideration need to take in concern before taking the final decision. The first question is - 
is this really a show-stopper? or A dead lock situation? or Performance issue? If with all consideration you are decided that this is a must, some caution need to 
perform to achieve the changes-

Step-1: Take a full database backup.

Step-2: Make sure the backup is restore-able. Make several copy of backup and preserve in different Server. This will help restore your OLD data in case of any accidental data lose.

Step-3: Make necessary changes to Development server first. Check your application performing as before without any issue specially where there are data access exist for the changed area.

Step-4: Check all database objects like (SP,FUNCTION) are using that table are still performing as expected.

Step-5: Better if you can engage some QA resource before make changes in LIVE environment.

Step-6: If all above steps goes fine, you can go for LIVE changes.

Step-7: Engage QA resource again to make sure LIVE changes are also applied without any issue.

**Note:** No significant downtime is required. But always it is best if you can keep stop database access from your application during the database changes. This make sure no data will hamper during insert/edit/delete data from application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a must to convert it.
Is there steps that I should follow to convert it properly on live changes?

Comment: There are all common pre-cautions and applicable for any databases.

Comment: Regarding Alter script, I am getting in my MySQL 5.0 the scripts are as below-                    
ALTER SCHEMA `test`  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
 ALTER TABLE `test`.`bill` COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci ; I found some differences between your and my script. Hope you are aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. there will be any impact on our current data if i convert it. And is it better using utf8mb4 instead utf8 ?